# How would I save JSON outputed by an URL to a file in selenium using c#

Tags: c#, json, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, jsonserializer

I am creating an automation(for Chrome browser) using Selenium 3.4 in c# in which I have a Url that displays JSON content when it load.also, the JSON Url takes a lot of time as it contains around 22MB of data.I want to save that JSON content to a file(like text or CSV).I came across a code

```
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"D:\path.txt"))
{
     JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
     serializer.Serialize(file, _data);
}
```

but it is showing JsonSerializer is not accessible due to protection level.I am writing this inside main method which is also public.

thanks in advance.

Comment: i came across somewhere like this. can you check this.->using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    client.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
}

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1061298/save-json-file-from-url-using-csharp